# HTML DOM createElement in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

when i want to addChild in the html with Dom,i want to insert some 
 in it, but i confused in the for loop.
First time i try this:

```
<div id="whitespaces"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var br = document.createElment("br")
    var wh = document.getElementById("whitespaces");
    for (var count = 1; count < 11; count++){
        wh.appendChild(br);
    }
}
</script>
```

And the result is i just get **1 < br>** in the  html.

Then i try this:
    
    
    window.onload = function() {

```
    var wh = document.getElementById("whitespaces");
    for (var count = 1; count < 11; count++){
        wh.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
</script>
```

In this i get **10 < br >** in my html page.
So why the 2's result is different? 
**The variable br not equal the document.createElment("br")?**

Comment: `appendChild` moves its argument element to a new parent, it doesn't clone. You've to re-create the `br` every time before appending it, i.e. put `br = document.createElment("br")` in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `br` is a unique element. When you use `appendChild` it removes the element from where it was, and inserts it somewhere else. In addition to creating a new node everytime like in your second example, what you can do is clone the node:

```
var br = document.createElment("br")
var wh = document.getElementById("whitespaces");
for (var count = 1; count < 11; count++){
    wh.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
}
```

Comment: you means that i can use the first code in other place like <p> or something else just except <br> ? :)